# Not stopping at eclipse debug point

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java,i have setup eclipse java project.I have a set of classes in jars in a folder.I have also got the java files associated to those classes downloaded (i cant compile those java files,its just to read and debug at runtime).My issue is class files are packaged in a different way than the those what appears in java file.
eg:- ABC.java  is structured as platform\src\main\java\com\subplatform\sql\ABC.java

But package declared in java file if i open is 
com.subplatform.sql;

I think this is the reason the debug point is not getting honored.In the previous version's of this product

java files used to be structured as 
src\com\subplatform\sql\ABC.java

Thus it used to stop at the debug point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rename all the package information that contains `package com.[restOfPackageInfo]` to be `package java.com.[restOfPackageInfo]` and you should be all set. (Also, if there are any import statements, you'll need to add `java` in front of `com` there too.)

There's your problem:

Originally the file structure was "src\com\subplatform\sql\ABC.java"

But by creating a folder called `java` and placing the `com` folder inside, you're changing the path to be: "src\main\java\com\subplatform\sql\ABC.java"

So, essentially in the ABC file you see `package com.subplatform.sql;`. This is information that the compiler uses to compile the class. So you're compiler looks for a ABC.java in src with path `com.subplatform.sql` but there is no such folder.

Also, read up on packaging.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your source attachment path is wrong and should point to `platform\src\main\java\` instead of the project itself.

A debug point not being honored can mean two different things.

1) The debugger isn't stopping on line breakpoints. If the compiled class files don't have line and debug information, the JVM doesn't know when it's executing those lines and will not stop there. You should still be able to stop at method entries and when exceptions are thrown. Either way, your are always required to launch your application using Debug instead of Run.

2) The debugger is stopping, but the source is not found. For a JAR file, you should have the properties of the JAR's entry on the Java Build Path point to a location where the source files *exactly* match the layout of the jar so that `com/novice/to/sql/MyClass.class` has a `com/novice/to/sql/MyClass.java` relative to where ever the source attachment points. If the top level contents of the JAR file contains entries like "com", "org", and "net", that's what should be in the top level of the source directory or archive you're pointing to.